# System.Net.Mail The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, smtp

I got the following exception when trying to send email using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP host was not found.`

Inner exception:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized`

My email sending code is rather simple:

```
private async Task SendEmail(string to, string subject, string email)
{
    MailMessage msg = null;
    SmtpClient smtp = null;
    try
    {
        var set = Settings.Default;
        msg = new MailMessage(set.EmailFrom, to, subject, email);
        smtp = new SmtpClient(set.SMTPServer, set.Port)
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(set.EmailUsername, set.EmailPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error("Error on sending email", e);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (msg != null) msg.Dispose();
        if (smtp != null) smtp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This error does not happen each time, but rather often. I tried to google it but have not found anything useful. The internet connection seems to be stable when I get this error.

Any ideas why this could happen?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for not posting this as a comment, I don't have sufficient rep.

I run a process using a very similar implementation to that and I have had the same thing happen to me. Try reducing SMTP the timeout, a new connection will be refused if there are too many requests that haven't let go of their existing connection yet. It's helped with my specific implementation.

Comment: Quite strange, as SmtpClient.Dispose() should close the connection and I don't send new email until the previous one is sent, so there should be no more than 1 connection at a time. Anyway thank you for suggestion, I will try (cannot try right now, its on another computer).

Comment: My implementation is not set up to run async, so maybe there's another problem at work. Regardless, I hope that helps.

Comment: just curious, but what did you reduce it to? 20 seconds from your original code example seemed really high. are you sending large attachments in the messages?

Comment: No, the emails are small, I have set such timeout to avoid possible temporary network issues. I reduced it to 10 seconds but the result is the same. Do you think it is too high yet? What reasonable value would you advice, considering the emails contain just few lines of plain text?

Comment: I send simple text emails as well, and I have my timeout set to 500 (so half a second). Maybe that will work for you.